# Ignoring newline changes in smerge-diff-mine-other

Tags: whitespace, diff, vc

For me, `smerge-diff-mine-other` seems to ignore changes in the number of whitespace characters where there is whitespace, but I would sometimes like it to ignore all whitespace, including newlines - even if a newline was inserted where the was no newline before. How can I achieve that?

`C-c C-w` in the *vc-diff buffer created by `smerge-diff-mine-other` doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, all those diff options work line-by-line, and insertion/removal of newlines creates completely different lines so they don't see those changes as "just whitespace".

You need to use a word-based diff or something like that.  Emacs comes with one such functionality which is the "refined" highlighting.  It's available both in `smerge-mode` and in `diff-mode`.  IOW, try the `smerge-refine` or `diff-refine-hunk` commands, and if you like them you might like to set `diff-auto-refine-mode`.